# Host IPv6-only website and allow access to IPv4-only clients

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, dns

Lets say site.example.com runs only with AAAA records, and I wish to access that site from IPv4-only network, and I don't want to do tunneling neither other protocols that masquerades IPv4 over IPv6 addresses...

Is that possible? I'm struggling because I want to host a website and my provider is giving me only IPv6 public/global addresses, and not even one public IPv4 address.

Comment: are you saying you need some kind of IPv6 to IPv4 gateway but you don't want to use any kind of IPv6 to IPv4 gateway?

Comment: I'm saying I need to host an app/website on my network (that's only running ipv6). And majority of my clients are on IPv4-only networks. Should I deploy a tunnel to each of my clients/visitors??

Comment: Unless you have an IPv4 address, people trying to connect to you with only IPv4 will not be able to. Your clients/visitors really need to get IPv6, anyway. There are going to be more and more sites coming up with your situation because we are out of IPv4 addresses, and they are going to get more and more expensive so that only large companies with money will be able to afford them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv4 and IPv6 are separate protocols. So if you want IPv4 only clients to be able to access your IPv6 only server you will need some kind of gateway/proxy service that can provide an IPv4 address to clients and pass the traffic to you over IPv6.

Comment: For now the Cloudflare solution is ok: https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cloudflares-automatic-ipv6-gatewa/ . They offer a gateway to serve your IPv4 only customers/clients to your IPv6 only server.

Comment: In addition to Cloudflare, there's also Retevia (retevia.net) providing some IPv4-as-a-Service offerings. (I've never worked for or with them; they just sprang to mind in the context of adding IPv4 connectivity to IPv6-only environments.) Who is the provider who's refusing to offer IPv4 resources? Not trying to name-and-shame (as usual), it just presents a case for why adding IPv6 is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 and IPv6 are two completely separate protocols, and they do not communicate with each other. If you need to connect from one protocol to another, you need some mechanism like what you reject to do a conversion for you.

Most ISPs now support IPv6, and it is a simple matter for most people to get IPv6 directly from their ISP, or via 6rd from one of the free providers of this.

If your server only has IPv6, then there really isn't anything you can do for people that refuse to run any form of IPv6. The RIRs have run out of IPv4 addresses to assign to the ISPs, and it is going to be more and more difficult to get IPv4 addresses in the future. It is past time for people to at least use both protocols and prepare for the IPv6 future.